# Consume ASP.NET Core Web API from ASP.NET - that assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-3.5, asp.net-core-3.1

We have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API controller that is called from an ASP.NET web app using .NET 3.5 framework. The API controller is called via a `HttpWebRequest` and results in an error

> That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Both apps reside on the same shared hosting environment and domain. That is, both app's have the same domain but are in different folders (i.e. applications) in IIS. For instance, mywebsite.com/folder1 and mywebsite.com/folder2.

Here's a sample how asp.net web app calls the .net core web api:

```
 oRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.mywebsite.com/folder2/path/to/api")
With oRequest
.Method = "GET"
.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.Accept = "application/json"
.ContentLength = 0    
oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()
oReader = New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream)
'store results in string
sResult = oReader.ReadToEnd
End With
```

We checked the .NET trust level and both app's are set to "Full (Internal)". Also, we tried adding the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute to the controller but per MS, "Partially trusted code is no longer supported. This attribute has no effect in .NET Core."

Is there a way to call the api?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain more on "Both app's reside in the same shared hosting environment and domain". ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET 4.x are in general incompatible so they cannot be hosted in certain ways. "called via HttpWebRequest" is also ambiguous so you'd better edit the question to show some code.

Comment: With a little more digging, some more info about the error received: The action that failed was:
LinkDemand
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.